# Git: Merge remote files with local files?

Tags: git

I am new to Git and trying to figure this out.

I have cloned a remote repository, say ssh://repo to my local machine. After cloning, I edited some files, during which time the remote repository was also changed.

How can I update my local repository with the remote one, while maintaining both sets of changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just commit your changes to your local repository using

```
git commit
```

command. Now you never lose your changes! Then pull new changes from remote repository using

```
git pull
```

command. This command fetches a new changes and merge them with your changes. Usually there is no conflicts. In this case you free to push your changes to remote repository. Otherwise you need to resolve all conflicts, mark them resolved using

```
git add
```

command (just use hints from git status output) and commit this merge using

```
git commit
```

command.

Comment: Each time I use git pull, the response is "Already up-to date" and the files on my local machine do not have the changes that were made to the remote code. Any idea why?

Comment: @htrk123 It can happen in this case: you move to XXX branch and someone pushed its changes to YYY branch.

Comment: @htrk123 were these changes commited to the remote repository?

Comment: Another person edited files and pushed them to the remote repo, now I need to add the changes I've made locally to the changes that are on the remote repository

Comment: @htrk123 then git pull must work. Check the name of the remote branch. Use git branch -a to do this.

Comment: Did you see others changes 'git log remotes/origin/master' ? Try run 'git fetch --all' to fetch all changes from remote repository and then run 'git log remotes/origin/master' again.

Answer (score 2):

"git pull" will merge remote the remote changes into your local copy. If you want to maintain your changes independently, you can move the changes to a new branch before you pull. So if you haven't yet committed your changes, you could do something like this:

```
> git stash #stash the changes
> git branch dev_branch #create a new branch
> git checkout dev_branch #move to the new branch
> git stash apply #paste the changes into the new branch
> git checkout master #switch back to the master branch
> git pull #update the master branch
```

At the end of that you have one version of the code contains your changes (dev_branch) and one that matches the remote code (master). You can now work on your dev_branch independent of whatever happens to the remote code. (When you get to know git you;ll find this is a more "git" way of working - just working in your master branch and doing "git pull" to merge in remote changes is a more of a "subversion" way of working).

Answer (score 0):

you can use command 'git pull' and this flag merge conflicts if any.
If there are conflicts, resolve it and should do git commit